# Return false if action fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my **update** action to return **false** if the method **get_coordinate** can't get the coordinates.

How can I refactor this piece of code ?

My model: street_address, postal_code, latitude, longitude

Controller (update):

```
if @address.update(address_params)
       postal_code = address_params[:address_attributes][:postal_code]
       latitude, longitude =  get_coordinate(postal_code)
       @address.latitude = latitude
       @address.longitude = longitude
       @address.save
end
```

Comment: What does `get_coordinate` return if it can't fetch the co-ordinate?

Comment: The function return nil

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to,

```
if @address.update(address_params)
       postal_code = address_params[:address_attributes][:postal_code]
       latitude, longitude =  get_coordinate(postal_code)
       @address.latitude = latitude
       @address.longitude = longitude
       @address.save
       false if latitude.nil? || longitude.nil?
end
```

Comment: `if postal_code.nil? false : true` is not valid Ruby.

Comment: @Jordan : My bad, changed.

Comment: Your code doesn't take `get_coordinate`'s return value into account

Comment: My mind is not here, changed that, thanks @Stefan. Now it should work fine.